# White Line (bottom and right side screen) in Splash Screen Image iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, splash-screen, ios7.1

I have a image with right iPad Retina Resolution (2048x1536) as Splash Screen in a iOS 7.1 app.
The image launches good but appear a **white line in the bottom and in the right side** of the screen.
After this splash screen I have a view controller with the same image as background image and it is right (without white lines).

App is always launched in landscape mode (landscape left o landscape right).
The image is set in project "Target > General > Launch Images" by xcassets.

Status bar is always hidden (in .plist file)

How can I resolve this?

If more info is needed, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the image name as "Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"?

Comment: No, I renamed the image and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your image is in landscape resolution,set the image name as "Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"

and try once.